# How to Update Selected User Detail Data in MVC 4 razor C# using Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have written the code to update the value in user table.

```
var after = new USERDETAIL
            {
                ID = before.ID,               
                FullName = FullName, 
                CountryCode = Country,
                Contact = Phone,
                Email = Email,
                Address = Address,
                City = City,
                State = State,
                Postal = PostalCode,                               
            };
using (var db = new SMSEntities())
{
    try
    {
        db.USERDETAILS.Attach(after);
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.FullName).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.CountryCode).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.Contact).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.Email).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.Address).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.City).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.State).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.Postal).IsModified = true;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.Password).IsModified = false;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.UrlIPath).IsModified = false;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.TimeDate).IsModified = false;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.TotalBalance).IsModified = false;
        db.Entry(after).Property(x => after.Verified).IsModified = false;
        //db.Entry<USERDETAIL>(before).State = System.Data.EntityState.Detached;
        //db.Entry<USERDETAIL>(after).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
       db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This is updating the values in Table but I have set `.IsModified = false;` so that the values in Table are not updated but the code is still updating the values. When I check the data in table there are NULL values updated in

> Password,UrlIPath,TotalBalance,Verified

which I don't want to update. How can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be

```
db.Entry(after).Property(x => x.Password).IsModified = false;
db.Entry(after).Property(x => x.UrlIPath).IsModified = false;
db.Entry(after).Property(x => x.TimeDate).IsModified = false;
db.Entry(after).Property(x => x.TotalBalance).IsModified = false;
db.Entry(after).Property(x => x.Verified).IsModified = false;
```

Comment: Thank You so much it really help full and I have make replace all after.values to x.values which work perfectly now.